# Weak convergence of probability measure on $\mathscr{C[0,\infty]}$

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

What is the reason for considering the spaces of probability measures on the space of all continuous functions and then considering weak convergence there ? Is it that we can then  use Skorohod's theorem and then prove a.s. convergence in the space of continuous functions ? But, what is the meaning of it ? That space has nothing random. Does this make sense ?